# Cannot create cloudsearch int index field with boto 2.31.1

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-cloudsearch

I'm trying to create an index field in a cloudsearch domain using python and boto 2.31.1.

I can successfully create index fields for types 'text', 'int-array' and 'literal' but not 'int'

e.g.

This succeeds:

```
dom_comments.create_index_field('some_text_field', 'text')
```

But this fails:

```
dom_comments.create_index_field('some_int_field', 'int')
```

With this error:

```
JSONResponseError: JSONResponseError: 400 Bad Request
{u'RequestId': u'436bca63-11c3-11e4-be49-c9eca06e67ee', u'Error': {u'Message': u'missing     value for long type', u'Code': u'MalformedInput', u'Type': u'Sender'}}
```

The class of `dom_comments` is `boto.cloudsearch2.domain.Domain`

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer.

You have to specify a default value when you create an 'int' index_field. So this works:

```
dom_comments.create_index_field('some_int_field', 'int', default=0)
```

I was using python 2.7.3 on Debian Wheezy.